# Disable touches on layer/scene for pause

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create a pause menu for my game. Using `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]` works well, however my game sprites have their own ccTouch methods, so they can still be dragged around while the game is paused.

I'm creating the pause menu by creating a CCLayer over top of the existing scene, and then removing it and resuming when they hit resume.

Is there an easy way to perhaps make it so that perhaps ONLY the pause layer receives touches? Or any other alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some kind of lock and unlock for all of your layers, in which you will disable and enable any user interaction. Then just implement logic to translate lock/unlock commands to all lockable children. It can be implemented, for example, as some protocol